# Scroll on div is not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code :

```
const listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');
  listElm.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
    if(listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight) {
      this.loadMore();
    }
  });
```

The event is not fired, even if the div `infinite-list` contains enough html data to display; Any ides ? Btw is fired with `wheel` but I need to fired when `scroll`;

Comment: does your element have `overflow: scroll`? if not, you're scrolling the document, not your element.

Comment: @Layhout no, it does

Comment: try `document.addEventListener("scroll", e => console.log(e))` and see if anything logs to your console.

Comment: like this is working, have logs

Comment: @Layhout but I need the scroll on div, because I have 2 divs on my page and for each I should manage the scroll event

Comment: then you're scrolling the document. that is why `listElm.addEventListener('scroll', e => { .. }` not fired.

Comment: how I can manage that @Layhout ?

Comment: your element need a fixed height.

Comment: @Layhout I added : `<div class="day-panels" style="height: 400px" id="infinite-list">` but still not good

Comment: try set height to your element smaller than its content and set `overflow: scroll` and see if `listElm.addEventListener('scroll', e => { .. }` fired.

Comment: something like this `<div class="day-panels" style="height: 50px" id="infinite-list">`

Comment: @Layhout and overflow:scroll is mandatory, right ?

Comment: you can also use `overflow: auto`. basically, your element need to be scrollable for scroll event to fired.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use scroll listener for stuff like this, use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. With this you can observe an element and react whenever it intersects with either another element or the viewport.

You can observe an empty element at the end of your list and whenever it comes into view, load more items.

```js
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

callback = (entries, observer) => {
 console.log(entries, observer);
 if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
   loadMoreItems();
 }
}

// this is just mocking adding more items, you can ignore this function. 
loadMoreItems = () => {
  let newItems = 10;
  const list = document.getElementById('list');
  while (newItems--) { // do this until we reach 0, which is "false"
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.append('Some random text: ' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 7 ));
    list.appendChild(item);
  }
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(document.getElementById('observedEl'));
```

```css
li {min-height: 20vh;}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #a2a2a2;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
 <li> Item </li>
 <li> Item </li>
 <li> xxx </li>
 <li> ASDF </li>
 <li> Whatever </li>
 <li> One more </li>
</ul>
<div id="observedEl"></div>
```